# Automatic switching of source port with and without module-echo-cancel

Tags: pulseaudio, noise

I am running Ubuntu Mate 20.04 and I am trying to set up my audio devices on my laptop. I learned about [`module-echo-cancel`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#module-echo-cancel) and am now using it.

I have added the following to the pulse audio configuration near the end:

```
.ifexists module-echo-cancel.so
# https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PulseAudio#Microphone_echo/noise_cancellation
load-module module-echo-cancel use_master_format=1 use_volume_sharing=1 aec_method=webrtc aec_args="analog_gain_control=0 digital_gain_control=1 experimental_agc=0 noise_suppression=1 voice_detection=1 extended_filter=1" source_name=echoCancel_source sink_name=echoCancel_sink
set-default-source echoCancel_source
set-default-sink echoCancel_sink
.endif
```

I have since noticed that I can not set the port for this source in the GUI as I can with the default source. I have 2 sources. "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo" and `Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo` when I don't have the module loaded.

Without `module-echo-cancel`, when I plug in my headset into the mixed input and output 3.5mm jack, the audio sink connector switches from `Internal` to `Headset`. This is most likely because the module [`module-switch-on-port-available`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#module-switch-on-connect) is loaded. However when I plug the same headset into the 3.5mm jack the audio source does not automatically switch over. How can I achieve that?

With the echo cancel module it takes the selected audio port and applies it's filter to that. However I have to do 4 clicks to change it. First switching back to the unfiltered input, then switching the port and then switching back to the filtered input. Whenever I unplug my headset it switches back to the internal microphone, which has a very poor quality.

How can I switch automatically to the new source port? How can I make echo cancel automatically use the new source port if that is a different thing?

I have read through the pulseaudio documentation on freedesktop and the arch wiki, but I have found nothing that would help me. I thought `module-switch-on-port-available` would do it, but it was already loaded. It switches only the output ports automatically, not the input.

Pulse detects the headset microphone as it populates the drop down list in the gui, but it does not switch automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I too was plagued by this. I found hope using:
pactl load-module module-switch-on-connect

Then I realized that if you unplug the device it went back to the original source.

So to get around that:
while true; do pactl info | grep -q 'Default Source: alsa_input.pci-0000_00_0e.0.analog-stereo' && pactl set-default-source noechosource ; sleep 10; done &

I created an endless loop that sets the default source to the non echo source if the  source is ever the original source.

So for anyone having this issue:

> pactl load-module module-switch-on-connect
>
> while true; do pactl info | grep -q 'Default Source:
> alsa_input.pci-0000_00_0e.0.analog-stereo' && pactl set-default-source
> noechosource ; sleep 10; done &

Replace 'alsa_input.pci-0000_00_0e.0.analog-stereo' with your original default source. Also replace 'noechosource' with whatever you called your no echo source.

You can find your original source name by selecting it and using the command:
pactl info